# Object keys loop not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

not sure what the problem is with my code however i cannot get a simple div to render which is in an object keys loop. I know it loops through it 11 times because I have put a console log within and outputs a console.log 7 times, however, the div does not render at all. Any ideas:

```
class BookingView extends React.Component {
render () {
  const {color, booking} = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      <BookingHeader booking={booking} color={color}/>
      {Object.keys(booking).forEach(function(key,index) {
        <div>this is a test</div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`forEach` does not return any array. Use `map` instead like this

```
{Object.keys(booking).map(function(key,index) {
   return (<div key={key}>this is a test</div>)
})}
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to do using for each in the last one hour. thank you for helping

Answer (score 7):

Because `#array.forEach` returns undefined, use `#array.map` to return the custom elements from callback function, and finally `map` will return an array of all the elements.

Write it like this:

```
{
    Object.keys(booking).map((key,index)  => <div key={key}>this is a test</div>)
}
```

Also add `key` to each dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` returns `undefined`, which React doesn't render.

You probably wanted

1. To use `map`, and
2. To return something out of the callback

For instance, using an arrow function (the concise form has an implicit `return`):

```
class BookingView extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {color, booking} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <BookingHeader booking={booking} color={color}/>
        {Object.keys(booking).map(key => <div key={key}>this is a test</div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

*(Note I added the `key` attribute, as you'll need that when rendering lists.)*

Or a verbose arrow with explicit return:

```
class BookingView extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {color, booking} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <BookingHeader booking={booking} color={color}/>
        {Object.keys(booking).map(key => {
          return <div key={key}>this is a test</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

...or a `function` function as in your question:

```
class BookingView extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {color, booking} = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <BookingHeader booking={booking} color={color}/>
        {Object.keys(booking).map(function(key) {
          return <div key={key}>this is a test</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```